# InvalidOperationException when calling SaveChanges with Foreign Keys and Remove

Tags: c#, entity-framework

After removing an object in my entity and calling SaveChanges(), I get an **InvalidOperationException**.

The problem is something to do with foreign keys, but there isn't any information in the exception that helps.

> The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.

I have a databound listbox.  I am trying to select a value in there and delete (remove) it from the entity.  That part (appears) to work, but when I call **SaveChanges()**, I get the exception.

// Code snippet:

```
MatchDate md = (MatchDate)lbDatesOfPlay.SelectedValue;
SelectedMatch.MatchDates.Remove(md);
```

I've checked as best I can, and I can't see anything being null (when I put a breakpoint on the SaveChanges() call).

Comment: What are the foreign key properties? Some other table seems to depend on `MatchDates`, and has a foreign key which is not nullable. You'll either need to delete all the rows which depend on the `MatchDates` row you're deleting, or else change those rows to refer to a different `MatchDates` row first.

Comment: Check all references on the entity you want to delete. If there is a reference from or to it, you will get this exception.

Comment: No other table references anything in MatchDates, although MatchDates does contain a reference to MatchesID, but I didn't think that would matter, until I saw @JoeJoe87577 comment.

Comment: The SQL server checks, if you enabled this on table creation, all references. This prevents records without or with broken references.

Comment: In Addition to @JohnSaunders you should check the mapping of the 2 entities.